# Java Regexp matching exact word

Tags: java, regex

I have this java regular expression.

```
        Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("(\\£\\d[\\d\\,\\.]+)[k|K]");
        Matcher finder = regex.matcher(price);
        if(finder.find()){
               etc;
        }
```

Note ... java

I'm trying to match whole word k or K not kilo or kilometer.  IVe tried \\bk\\b but the online testers show no match.  Has it something to do with square brackets.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Did you try to use just one `\\b`? `£\\d[\\d,.]*[kK]\\b`?

Comment: no 2 slashes  \\b I meant

Comment: I am not speaking of slashes. Did you use *one* word boundary at the end of the pattern? Or always added another one before `k`?

Comment: I added 2 word boundaries (\\£\\d[\\d\\,\\.]+)[\\bk\\b|\\bK\\b]

Comment: @JoeC I think that is unfair.  THere is alot of misinformation out there.  Some stackoverflow questions have several upticks for \\bwords\\b.   THe correct answer is below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Beside the fact that currently your pattern matches a `k` or `K` before any char, it does not match values like `£1k` as the `+` quantifier requires another digit, dot or comma before `k` or `K`.

Also note that `[\\b]` does not match a word boundary, it only matches a `b` letter.

Putting a `\b` between `[\\d\\,\\.]+` and `[k|K]` is not a good idea since there is always a word boundary between `.` / `,` and `k`, and there is no word boundary between a digit and `k`.

You need to use

```
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("(£\\d[\\d,.]*)[kK]\\b");
```

**Details**

- `(£\\d[\\d,.]*)` - Group 1:

  - `£` - a pound sign
  - `\\d` - a digit
  - `[\\d,.]*` - zero or more digits, `,` or `.`
- `[kK]` - a `k` or `K`
- `\\b` - a word boundary (there must be end of string or a non-word char after `k` or `K`)